# Angular Material Layout Bug? Cards Are Overlapping

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, debugging

I want to use the responsive [layout](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/layout/container) from material.angularjs.org to display two [cards](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdCard).

On a "real" website, the cards are overlapping on small screens:
[Real world example no longer exists]

However, it works when I copy/paste the very same html/js code into a stackoverflow snippet!

---

**Big screen: works fine:**

[image]

**Small screen: cards overlap!**

[image]

---

To illustrate better, what it is about, I inserted the code snippet I use on the website below with dummy content:

```js
  (function(){
   'use strict';

   angular
    .module('BlankApp', ['ngMaterial'])
   ;
      })();
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0/angular-material.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700,400italic">

<!-- Angular Material requires Angular.js Libraries -->
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-messages.min.js"></script>

 <!-- Angular Material Library -->
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>

<main ng-app="BlankApp" ng-cloak class="md-content">
  
<div layout="row" layout-xs="column">
  <div flex>
    <md-card>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="md-card-image" alt="Washed Out">
      <md-card-title>
        <md-card-title-text>
          <span class="md-headline">Action buttons</span>
        </md-card-title-text>
      </md-card-title>
      <md-card-content>
        <p>
          The titles of Washed Out's breakthrough song and the first single from Paracosm share the two most important words in Ernest Greene's musical language: feel it. It's a simple request, as well...
        </p>
      </md-card-content>
      <md-card-actions layout="row" layout-align="end center">
        <md-button>Action 1</md-button>
        <md-button>Action 2</md-button>
      </md-card-actions>
    </md-card>
  </div>
  <div flex>
    <md-card>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="md-card-image" alt="Washed Out">
      <md-card-title>
        <md-card-title-text>
          <span class="md-headline">Action buttons</span>
        </md-card-title-text>
      </md-card-title>
      <md-card-content>
        <p>
          The titles of Washed Out's breakthrough song and the first single from Paracosm share the two most important words in Ernest Greene's musical language: feel it. It's a simple request, as well...
        </p>
      </md-card-content>
      <md-card-actions layout="row" layout-align="end center">
        <md-button>Action 1</md-button>
        <md-button>Action 2</md-button>
      </md-card-actions>
    </md-card>
  </div>
</div>
  </main>
```

---

### How can this unwanted card overlapping be solved?

Comment: this works good on my screen (mac / chrome)

Comment: are you sure you haven't included bootstrap also or just another css library
I had similar problem it was because bootstrap was overwriting some classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works for me. In a CSS file overwrite this CSS line from `angular-material.min.css`.

```
@media (max-width: 599px)
.layout-xs-column>.flex {
     min-height: 0;
}
```

with:

```
@media (max-width: 599px)
.layout-xs-column>.flex {
     min-height: auto;
}
```

I have no experience with material.angularjs.org but it could be hotfixed like this.

Comment: Thank you, this hot fix works indeed! However, I still need to know if I am doing something wrong or if I discovered a bug that needs fixing.

Comment: No problem. Not sure how it works on smaller devices but min-height: 0 should be removed from the css completely if your html is valid and can be considered as bug. Else you could check your html against the one in the documentation to see if the html is valid. There isn't much more you can do than that two things. :)